# Convert array into array from absolute values only

Tags: java, arrays

I have trouble converting negative array elements into absolute. So far ive made array containing both negative and positive, but i have to convert them into absolute, in order to calculate array square root. Any suggestions?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int min = -100;
    int max = 100;

    int[] array = new int[201];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        array[i] = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));

        //System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

    int[] array2 = new int[array.length];
    for (int j = 2; j < array.length; j += 3) {
       array2[j] = array[j];
       //System.out.println(array[j]);



        double[] result = new double[array2.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length / 3; i++) {

            array2[i] = Math.abs(i);
            result[j] = Math.sqrt(array[j]); 
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Make an if statement to check if the number is < 0. If it is, multiply by -1

Comment: Also, am I to assume you have three seperate for loops or are the last two nested?

Comment: yes, 3 for loops, 1st one to create basic array, 2nd to extract every 3th element into separate array and the 3th one should be for converting negative>absolutes.

Comment: Why don't you use Math.abs()? For example `result[j] = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(array[j]));

Comment: result[j] = Math.sqrt(array[j]); should be result[j] = Math.sqrt(array2[j]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clearly describe your intentions, 
it is no clear that you want each third element of the array and not every one of them.

However there are multiple ways to achive the result.

1. You can create a `List` to store square root of each third element

   ```
   List<Double> result1 = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int j = 2; j < array.length; j += 3) {
       result1.add(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(array[j])));
   }
   ```
2. If you would like to use arrays make it like so

   ```
   double[] result2 = new double[array.length / 3];
   for (int j = 2; j < array.length; j += 3) {
       result2[j / 3] = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(array[j]));
   }
   ```

In both examples we call `Math.abs` to get the absolute value and `Math.sqrt` to get square root.

Here is the full code

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int min = -100;
    int max = 100;

    int[] array = new int[201];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
    }

    List<Double> result1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 2; j < array.length; j += 3) {
        result1.add(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(array[j])));
    }

    double[] result2 = new double[array.length / 3];
    for (int j = 2; j < array.length; j += 3) {
        result2[j / 3] = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(array[j]));
    }

    System.out.println(result1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your third-last line is wrong, you need:

```
result[j] = Math.sqrt(array2[j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Math.abs()` on `i` (the index) not on the array element. Also, you are storing the result of abs into `array2[i]` and then calling `Math.sqrt()` on a different array and element (`array[j]`). Also check if your for loop indexes iterate the fields in the way you want (to me the for loop statements seem somewhat strange).